# Creating self signed certs on linux server and using them on windows client?

Tags: c#, ssl, networking, mosquitto

I have a linux server and a windows host which I am trying to set up using SSL/TLS. I have created a CA on the server and generated the certs needed on this machine, I then added them to the ca-certs and copied the CA and cert to the client machine. I converted the .pem cert file to .cer and added both the CA and .cer files to the trusted certs using mmc command.

Now when I run the server and fire up the client the handshake is not completed and the server just hangs until the connection is timed out , really struck so any advice would be appreciated.

At the moment the client is written in C# and I am using the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback to validate the server certs:

```
private bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("checking for ssl-policy-errors -->");
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            // if got an cert auth error
            Console.WriteLine("checking ssl-policy-errors for name mismatch -->");
            if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch) return false;
            const string sertFileName = @"C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\M2MAuth\webservercert.pem";

            // check if cert file exists
            if (File.Exists(sertFileName))
            {
                var actualCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(sertFileName);
                Console.WriteLine("checking if file exists -->");
                return certificate.Equals(actualCertificate);
            }
            return false;
}
```

Comment: How is it related to c#? Are you creating these certs programatically?

Comment: At the moment the client is written in C# and I am using the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback to validate the server certs:

Comment: What kind of SSL/TLS? If mutual, you need to install the client certificate in PFX format to the proper certificate store so that your C# code can find it.

Comment: I would never comapre certs with `Equals`, rather, comapre thumbprints and subject names.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla Thanks, I will update the method to compare the thumbprints and subject names.

Comment: @Lex Li Should I do this conversion on the Linux server where the certs are generated or on the client (Windows) machine where the certs will be stored or does it matter?

Comment: @DVN OpenSSL on either OS is OK but you need to merge the private key of the client certificate with the .cer file itself to a .pfx file.

Comment: @Lex Li Hi thanks for the reply, I implemented your suggestion but there is still no change.  I am using a peer-to-peer connection and when server passes the cert nothing happens - it frustrating because I don't get an error, the connection just times out.  However if I use the allow method (above) I can create the connection.  But I am not sure if this is the correct way of initiating the connecting or not, do I have to handle the certification myself.

Comment: You only list some code, so it is impossible to tell further what's up. Certificates themselves can be the cause, but your code might simply just be incorrect.

Comment: @Lex Li thanks for the time in answering my questions, I have it working using the the .pfx cert file and changing some conflicting variables in the mosquitto.conf file.  Thanks once again.

Comment: Then you might post your findings as an answer and accept it.